# How to determine the datatype of a variable

Tags: types, common-lisp

It is an easy to answer question (I guess), but I looked for a while not finding anything so I will direct my question to you.

There is the `typep` to determine whether a given variable is of some specific data-type e.g. integer,hashtable etc. , but is there a function which returns the data-type?

e.g.

```
(defvar *x* 1)
*x*

(typep *x* 'integer)
T

(the-type-function *x*)
INTEGER
```

Comment: Though, to nitpick, the type is actually attached to the *object* (stored in a variable), not to the variable.

Comment: Rainer Joswigs answer fit my needs, as I had a Class I could not identify but needed its type to check for it before calling some functions on it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> There is the typep to determine whether a given variable is of some specific data-type e.g. integer,hashtable etc. ,

Not really. In Common Lisp variables are not typed as you think.

```
(defvar *x* 1)
*x*

(typep *x* 'integer)
T
```

Above says nothing about the type of a variable `*x*`. It confirms that the object `1` is of type `integer`.

> but is there a function which returns the data-type?

Not really. There is a function `TYPE-OF`, which returns the type of an object, not of a variable.

```
> (type-of 1)
FIXNUM
```

There is no difference when we get the value from a variable.

```
> (type-of *x*)
FIXNUM
```

But that does not mean the variable has that type.

Note: Common Lisp has types and type declarations. But that looks slightly different.

Comment: Thanks, type-of is the perfect answer to my question.